# Webhooks subscribe/publish with queue

Tags: stack, publish-subscribe, webhooks

I am trying to implement application on proxy server which will provide instant notifications based on web hooks.

How it is going to work is:
Client sends a subscribe http request to server providing callback url 
something like:

```
http://example.com/subscribe?callbackurl=&other_parameters=
```

That request will be saved. Later (when event within server occurs) we are going to send notification to that callback url containing data.

I can implement this by myself, but simple app right now is not solution because it needs to handle huge traffic (like 1 - 2 millions responses per day) without losing requests and without choking.

Because of that, I am wondering is there any kind of open source solution with full stack implementation you can suggest (or solution which i need to pay but possible to configure and host on my own server) which have things i mentioned above and which scales really good when we are taking about huge traffic.

When i say full stack implementation, I am referring on software which i can install on my server, then i can publish a message to a queue or something like that from script within the server, and then stack will to the rest (will queue the message, will check subscribers, will publish/send response to callback, handling huge traffic and a lot of requests internally).

What i want is something like http://www.iron.io/ but on my own server. iron.io seems to be great solution (where you can configure how much retries you want etc..)  but it is cloud based and i am not able to use solution like that.

Am i able to use http://resthooks.org/ and configure/implement my own system for queuing? Anyone tried it before, can you please share your experience?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** Even i thought that subscribe/response services with full stack are quite popular after detailed research i implemented my own solution.

Comment: what was your final solution like?

Comment: Its not that simple to just "show you solution". Implementation of full stack took 2 months in order to be able to support 1000msg/sec on decent servers.

Comment: Understood. My questions was more like what was the technology stack that you have used. Thank You.

Comment: node in combination with redis and rabbitmq to avoid bottlenecks... its not mandatory of course to use those, but the bottom point is that you will need to have a system for queuing messages if you dont want to lose incoming messages due to the high traffic